# How to pass a file using Xcode in arguments

Tags: xcode

Sorry about my poor English, I hope you can understand what I'm describing

I know how to pass arguments, like -v, -c, etc

> Edit Scheme > Run xxx > Arguments

In Termimal.app, when I type the following, it shows the correct result, as expected.

```
./C_Product < main.c
```

How should I do this in Xcode?
I tried to add argument `< main.c`, but it did not affect.

I already copied main.c file to

> C_Productxxxxx -> Build -> Products -> Debug

with `C_Product` at the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get Xcode to pipe the contents of a file to std in automatically. However, you do have some other options. You could modify your program to take the filename as an argument, and then pass in the filename as an argument as you have above. So you could make `-i <foo>` be the name of the input file. (Or better yet, `-input-file <foo>`.)

Alternatively, you could modify your application to read from a file whose path is in an environment variable. So your app could call `getenv("MY_INPUT_FILE");` and you could tell Xcode to set the value of "MY_INPUT_FILE" environment variable to the path of the input file in the scheme.